# Sorting object keys by number then letter in Typescript or Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object which looks like the following

```
{
  "8 am": 2,
  "11 am": 6,
  "12 pm": 3,
  "5 pm": 7,
  "1 pm": 0
}
```

I am using the code below to sort the object using keys.

```
const ordered: any = {};
Object.keys(groupedData).sort().map((key) => {
     ordered[key] = groupedData[key];
});
```

I get a result as follows

```
 {
  "1 pm": 0,
  "8 am": 2,
  "11 am": 6,
  "12 pm": 3,
  "5 pm": 7,
}
```

However what I require is something like this

```
 {
  "8 am": 2,
  "11 am": 6,
  "12 pm": 3,
  "1 pm": 0,
  "5 pm": 7
}
```

How can I achieve this in typescript or javascript. Solutions with plugins are also welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a function which can transform the string into its associated hour value (eg, `8 am` -> `8`, `3 pm` -> `15`), then `.sort` by that function:

```js
const groupedData = {
  "8 am": 2,
  "11 am": 6,
  "12 pm": 3,
  "5 pm": 7,
  "1 pm": 0
}
const ordered = {};
const getVal = (str) => {
  if (str === '12 pm') {
    return 12;
  }
  const [num, ampm] = str.split(' ');
  return (ampm === 'pm') * 12 + Number(num);
};
Object.keys(groupedData).sort((a, b) => getVal(a) - getVal(b)).map((key) => {
  ordered[key] = groupedData[key];
});
console.log(ordered);
```

More elegantly, using `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const groupedData = {
  "8 am": 2,
  "11 am": 6,
  "12 pm": 3,
  "5 pm": 7,
  "1 pm": 0
}

const getVal = (str) => {
  if (str === '12 pm') {
    return 12;
  }
  const [num, ampm] = str.split(' ');
  return (ampm === 'pm') * 12 + Number(num);
};
const ordered = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(groupedData).sort((a, b) => getVal(a[0]) - getVal(b[0]))
);
console.log(ordered);
```

Comment: You cannot ensure the order of keys in and object.

Comment: Yes you can, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58444013 All implementations follow it, and the specification will soon guarantee it too

Comment: @Tatenda Press "Run code snippet" - the keys *are* kept in 12 hour format. This does not change the keys, only their order.

Comment: @CertainPerformance (ampm === 'pm') * 12 + Number(num); is telling me that *The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type* in typescript.. any solution

Comment: @Tatenda You can cast to number explicitly for Typescript: `Number(ampm === 'pm')`

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom function to sort the keys:

```
function sortHours(a, b) {
  const [aParsed, bParsed] = [a, b].map(x => {
    let [num, str] = x.split(' ');
    num = str === 'pm' ? num + 12 : num;
    return num;
  })
  return aParsed > bParsed ? 1 : -1;
}
```

And sort them:

```
Object.keys(a).sort(sortHours)
```

You should also leave sorted object as array, since Javascript doesn't retain order on object keys.

Comment: This will put `12 pm` at the bottom, when it should be in the middle. *since Javascript doesn't retain order on object keys.* It does retain key order, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58444013

Comment: That depends on the locale.